# Java alt codes as string

Tags: java, string, netbeans, stringbuilder

So as in my previous question, I want to add alt+ codes to my project, specifically ☆

I'm using this as my code:

```
    totalStars.append("\u9733");
    totalStarsLabel.setText(totalStars.toString());
```

I also tried:

```
    totalStars.append("☆");
    totalStarsLabel.setText(totalStars.toString());
```

But i get this as an output: ▛

Any idea how to fix this? I'm really stumped.

SOLVED:

use Unicode (the font used in the Netbeans source code) and ("\u2605")

Comment: This might hint to a font problem. What is totalStars, what is totalStarsLabel?

Comment: totalStars is a StringBuilder, and totalStarsLabel is a label on a JFrame in one of my frames. The font is Ravie, does that make a difference?

Comment: It makes a difference if Ravie doesn't have a Star type character (or doesn't store a Star type character at \u9733). For the hell of it, try a few different fonts. TNR and Helvetica and whatnot. If they do the same thing, then I guess I'm off base.

Comment: I changed it to Times New Roman and the heart symbol worked (2665) but not the star :/ i don't know of any other code for star

Comment: You could try whatever font you are using in your editor (as you seem to see the star symbol there)

Comment: okay, so I did that but I'm getting weird chinese letters. Guess I better find a different alt code ':) But it works thanks!

Comment: please post the solved section of your question as answer! thanks

Answer (score 0):

That u9733 if indeed the 9733 is hexadecimal and it should be hexadecimal then it is in the middle of CJK ideographs territory. This intrusion into CJK may be for less than honorable reasons....

Is this what you are working with?
http://www.fonts2u.com/ravie.font

Comment: I don't understand any of that....but i did fix it:) I used `("u\2605")` and yes that's the font i was using, now I'm using Unicode